# What are some challenges with building web apps using Salesforce as a back-end?

Tags: api, force.com-sites

My company is developing a custom web app (PHP/React) that relies on a lot of data coming from Salesforce. The app is targeting external customers and not existing Salesforce users.

Our initial plan was to develop some sort of integration between the two systems, but lately, I've been thinking about using Salesforce as a back-end for most of the work and have the web app as a thin layer on top providing sign in / sign up functionality and a light SQL database to store some data that doesn't necessarily need to reside in Salesforce.

I'm aware of the Salesforce API limits and a lot of that could be circumvented by having an API gateway that caches responses so it goes to SF only when absolutely necessary.

Are there some issues with this approach that I'm not seeing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At a broader level, there is no definitive right or wrong approach to your question. It totally depends on the tech stack you are going to choose for this integration and the business requirements/ criticality. This may not be the exact answer you are looking for and there will always be issues/ workarounds with the technical implementation. So, I've tried to list few things that should be considered. You should consider as many things as possible that may (or may not) go wrong with the new application. Some of them are:

- What is the volume of data that needs immediate replication? Is there any critical data that could impact business adversely in case of lag in replication?
- What is the trend of data volume increase at your company? Will the light SQL database be scalable in future to handle data load, if needed?
- What about the current data security model? How are you planning to implement record level and object level permission for the data that will be moved into light SQL database?
- What is the long term cost of building a full blown web application vs integration modules?
- By simply using Salesforce as a backend, you will most likely loose out many UI features and upcoming features in future releases. Are you seeing any benefit with your approach when compared to loosing out on this?
- What is the likely best case adoption rate for the new web application by end users over Salesforce?

There could be many more points to be considered depending on your implementation details.  And, the above points is not discourage you from trying out your approach, but to prompt about thinking towards possible problems.

---

**Update:**

- With reference to data/ application scalability: Is your application going to handle daily/ weekly/ monthly transactional data or Is there going to be reporting/ dashboards that would be based on large volume of historical data?

If its just going to be transactional data, I don't think you would run into huge scalability issues. You can always have mechanism in place that would ensure that the older data is pushed into SF and archive/ purge the same in the local storage.

If its going to be large volume of historical data, there is a fair chance of hitting scalability issues in future. This can be circumvented by additional storage or caching, which comes at extra cost. This is something you should research based on which local DB (postgres, any NOSQL DB etc.) you are going to use (rather than looking from Salesforce point of view). Each DB would have its own pros & cons.

---

Comment: Thank you. The application we’re building isn’t targeting a subset of our Salesforce users. We are targeting external customers so permissions and an out of the box UI aren’t a concern as we cannot benefit from those. My main concern is whether this is scalable as I’ve been struggling to find any examples of using Salesforce as a database back-end for consumer web applications.

Comment: I guess I should have been a bit more attentive while reading your question about the target end users. I've updated my answer with this reference. With respect to scalability, I thing you really ought to decide on which local DB you are going to use and then look at it in detail (keep it separate from SF; at least during the initial research). I've also updated my answer in this reference.

Comment: The odds of finding examples relevant to your requirement is quite less (I've tried to search in this reference in the past). I would assume that only a handful of organizations would have implemented this. It sounds like you have thought thru well regarding this requirement and you are trying to segregate low-interactive parts of the application into different systems, which is a good approach.